# AngularJS route with routeprovider not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this index.html page:

```
<html>
<head ng-app="myApp">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test App/title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <a href="#/index2">index2</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my app.js script:

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/index2', {
                templateUrl: 'views/index2.html'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/views/index2.html'});
    });
myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
});
```

And my views/index2.html is contains only single 123 element.
When I'm clicking link on my index.html, nothing happens, no routing.
What I'm doung wrong?

upd: I run it from IntelliJ IDEA so it's nothing about webserver is missing ,I think.

Comment: anything on console?

Comment: canu see the request for `views/index2.html` in network ?

Comment: no, there's no request for it in Chrome Network tab.

Comment: @dotnetom gave the answer i think :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `ng-app` directive applied to your `head` tag:

```
<head ng-app="myApp">
```

This means that `ng-app` will apply to `head` tag only. Instead you need to move it to your `html` tag:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```